# Count number of given object in a list with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list which can contain multiple occurrences of the same object. Now I need to count, how often the given object is contained in this list.

```
int count = 0;
foreach (IMyObject item in myList)
  if (item == object2Count)
    count++;
```

I am sure that this can be done nicer with LINQ, but LINQ is still a mystery to me.

My first question is: How would I count the objects via LINQ and the second question: Will this LINQ version be slower or faster? I am using a ObservableCollection and the number of items in the list is usally rather small ... usally not more then 20.

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can easily count objects in a collection using the [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) extension method. Either:

```
var count = myList.Where(item => item == object2Count).Count();
```

or

```
var count = myList.Count(item => item == object2Count);
```

With regards to performance it should be the same as the `foreach` loop.

(Your predicate `item == object2Count` looks a bit weird but that is not related to the question about how to count objects in a collection.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now that I see the answer, it seems to be obvious this way :D. As for my predicate, what is weird about it and how would you suggest to write it in an other way?

Comment: @Aaginor: If `==` is using reference equality and you don't store the same instance more than once in the collection `count` will be 0 or 1. So basically you are determning if `object2Count` belongs to the collection. There are more efficient ways to determine that using the `Any` extension method. If on the other hand you have overriden the `==` operator your predicate is fine.

Comment: I do not create a duplicate object to be stored, but store the same reference multiple times. (Like IMyObject o = new MyObject(); myList.Add(o); myList.Add(o);) (Or at least I believe that I do store the same object :D )

Comment: @Aaginor: If you want to count how many times a specific reference is stored in the collection your predicate is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = myList.Count(x => x == object2Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var count = objectlist.Count(x => x == object2Count));
```

Comment: -1 - this query doesn't return the count of instances of `object2Count` but the number of objects of class `ObjectClass`

Comment: This is wrong, he's not looking for all objects of a certain class, but for a specific object

Answer (score 0):

[Look at 101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747#countSimple)

int count = myList.Count(item  => item == object2Count);