# how to check how many times an item exists in list in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

do you know how to check how many times an item exists in a c# list? I've tried with

```cs
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    numbers.Add(1);
    numbers.Add(1);
    numbers.Add(2);
    numbers.Add(2);
    Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count);
```

but it's count of items in list (4 items) but i want that there are two "1" and two "2". Do you know how to do this? Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of given object in a list with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408972/count-number-of-given-object-in-a-list-with-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a grouping and then create a dictionary from it using LINQ:

```
Dictionary<int, int> numberFrequency = numbers
    .GroupBy(n => n)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Then to find out how many times 4 occurred, you can check like so:

```
int toFind = 4;
if (!numberFrequency.TryGetValue(toFind, out int frequency))
{
    frequency = 0;
}
Console.WriteLine($"{toFind} occurred {frequency} time(s).");
```

Or you can loop through:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kv in numberFrequency)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key} occurred {kv.Value} time(s).");
}
```

[Docs for GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1)

[Docs for ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netcore-3.1)

You might also need [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1) or [OrderByDescending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netcore-3.1).

---

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/ZJUD68966)

Comment: thanks i will try this